# Storybook- Does data in args override api data in component?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm trying to build my storybook by simply importing a reusable component into stories.

The component takes API data that are being sent outside it to render the UI.  I know this is asynchronous and I'm not going to fetch data in storybook, so I have set a static data in args of storybook like this.  But then I've encountered the error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
“

```
import NewAssignee from "./NewAssignee"
//import child component
...storybook code
export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
data: [
      {
        icon: "some url",
        title: "some username",
      },
      {
        icon: "another url",
        title: "another username",
      },
    ]
```

When I run storybook, these data appears in the control section.

The component originally takes API data as props like this

```
function parent(){
 
     const fetchedData = useGetAllIssuesQuery({
    baseType: "repos",
    type: "/labels",
    name: "/usename",
    repo: "/reponame",
    query: "",
  });
//API data from RTK query, fetching issue from Github open API

  const[data,setData]=useState();

   useEffect(()=>setData(fetchedLabelData),[fetchedLabelData])

//data is set from API then pass as props.

  return(
   <NewAssignee data={data} />
)

}
```

The simplified component code is as follow

```
function NewAssignee({data}){
   if(data===undefined){
     return <></>
}
return(
    <>
      {data.map((item)=>(
            ...{item.title}
            ...{item.icon}
    </>
         )
      }
```

As the component is a bit large, please let me know if I need to provide more details.

And the data is fetched from RTK Query then set through setState in original component.

Could someone shed some light on this?  I'm not sure if the component would take the API data or my static data first.

Comment: Kindly provide the component code.

Comment: Sure! Will update it right away

Comment: I don't see anything in the component that performs any asynchronous process to populate `data`. There shouldn't be any instances where it would yield `undefined`

Comment: Oh, the async process is actually preform in the parent component.  I've updated the code in above.  Sorry for not having enough info as I'm afraid I'd provide too many info and confuses people who want to answer.

Comment: So which component is being consumed by Storybook right now? The parent component of the `NewAssignee` component?

Comment: It's the NewAssignee component.